# Python urllib2() functions with international/UTF-8 characters

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, urllib2

For a personal research/fun project I am using the Python urllib2() function.  However, when I have a link with non-ASCII chars, say, "الراجل اللى ورا عمر سليمان" or "我爸是李刚" then the interpreter (IDLE in Windows 7) runs into problems.

```
s = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bing.com/search?q=我爸是李刚")
```

How should I go about rectifying this?  (Should I convert my query into ASCII or is there a way to have urllib2 work with UTF-8 another way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bing.com/search?"
              + urllib.urlencode({ 'q' : u'我爸是李刚' .encode('utf8') } )
```

Should work.

Comment: Works great -- that's all I needed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
# coding: utf-8

import urllib
import urlparse

scheme = 'http'
netloc = 'www.bing.com'
path = '/search'
qs = {'q': u'我爸是李刚'.encode('utf-8')}

print urlparse.urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, '', urllib.urlencode(qs), ''))

# http://www.bing.com/search?q=%E6%88%91%E7%88%B8%E6%98%AF%E6%9D%8E%E5%88%9A
```